# How to set order in which files packaged during build in Angular

Tags: angular, deployment, build

I have Angular project that needs to support localization. To do that we load translations from json files before module loaded. In main.ts I added following lines:

```
loadTranslationsFromJson(extractUserLocale(), 'assets/i18n').then(m => {
  platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

All is working except for some const variables declared in services outside of the class. For example:

```
const commonPhrase = $localize`Enter your birthday`;
@Injectable()
export class OnboardingService {
  // any variables declared here with $localize work fine
}
```

As I understand in example above since `const commonPhrase` loaded at Javascript load/compile time in browser its not part of the Angular module thus its created before call to `bootstrapModule(AppModule)`. As result variable `commonPhrase` will not be translated.

It tells me that if I can make sure that in deployed package (which is large JS file) my main.ts file is injected first (thus will be executed by browser first) I can solve this issue. Is there way during build to specify order in which files added to the bundle? Or how to place main.ts as first in the bundle?

Comment: why can't you declare it inside service class as a readyonly property? as you are not exporting this constant, so you can keep it inside class as a readonly property.

Comment: I personally can but since we have about 20 developers someone will make that mistake. I prefer to automate or eliminate potential source for bugs. If I cant find solution then will fallback to enforcing it via PRs.

Comment: create a method to internationalize such string globally and wrap your string around it. you can't control it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Figured the answer. Its not the order of the module/files in ht ebuild but order in which they activated/imported.
If you look at main.js which is your bundle for the main app module you will see all the modules/serice/componets etc as hashmap in there. Order does not matter but I found that what matter is what module imported first. I created separate module for the bootstrapping localization and add it as top import for the AppModule. This did it.